# Butterknife with IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've been trying all day to get butterknife to work in IntelliJ but no joy.

I've added the lib (tried both manually and through Maven) and have ensured that Annotation Processing is enabled but my views are still null after calling Views.inject(this).

Does anyone have a step by step list of actions to get this working?

```
package com.techinc.MyProgressives;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.Views;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @InjectView(R.id.txtOutput)EditText txtOutput;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Views.inject(this);

        txtOutput.setText("hello doug");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just finally got this working. For those in the same boat:

1. File -> Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors.
2. Tick Enable annotation processing

This is as far as I got through googling.
Then:

1. Make sure you don't use the option to obtain processors from project classpath, set your processor path to the butterknife jar.
2. Make sure you select "Module content root" for "Store generated sources relative to".

Job done!

Answer (score 0):

The lasted version of idea have any change:
File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Compiler-> Annotation Processors.
Then tick Enable annotation processing